# Add <a> to every word inside <h3>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to add <"a"> to every word inside an <"h3">. The link should contain the word it has been wrapped around. The web page has many different h3's.

```
<h3>add links</h3>
<h3>to each word</h3>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<h3><a href="add">add</a> <a href="links">links</a></h3>
<h3><a href="to">to</a> <a href="each">each</a> <a href="word">word</a></h3>
```

I don't know if it's possible (or good) to use PHP else jQuery/JS would be good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use `html()` with callback function to update the value
2. For updating it with anchor tag use `replace()` with `regex`

```js
$('h3').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)/g, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>add links</h3>
<h3>to each word</h3>
```

To avoid encoded html entities try this code

```js
$('h3').html(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)/g, '$1<a href="$2">$2</a>$3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>add links</h3>
<h3>to each word</h3>
```

Comment: Ecellent! Thanks! Only a minor issue It removes & and puts &amp; instead.

Comment: @Algatella : glad to help :)

Comment: Any chance you could tell me how to deal with special characters? =)

Answer (score 1):

The code from the given answer won't work well with embedded tags and Unicode words.

Here is a better fool-proof alternative:

```js
$('h3').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).replaceWith(function() {
  return this.nodeValue.replace(/(\S+)(?=\s+|$)/g, '<a href="$&">$&</a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>add links to each word</h3>
<h3>with Юникод support & <i>ignoring</i> <em>this</em></h3>
```