# How to add a google search link to every word in html with performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, web-services, dom

I am trying to develop a web service that takes a url, and **add a google search link** to every word in the webpage returned from that url, and then return the modified html as the response.

say if the page has

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>the title</h3>
    <p>the long content</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to return something like

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <a href='https://www.google.com/?q=the'>the</a>
      <a href='https://www.google.com/?q=title'>title</a>     
    </h1>
    <p>
      <a href='https://www.google.com/?q=the'>the</a>
      <a href='https://www.google.com/?q=long'>long</long>
      <a href='https://www.google.com/?q=content'>content</a>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm seeing a lot of questions asking about the similar thing. Most of them do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31707903/9182558):

```js
$('h3').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/(\s*)(\w+)(\s*)/g, '$1<a href="https://google/com/?q=$2">$2</a>$3');
});
```

However, I am trying to handle **over 10000 concurrent requests per minute**(The original number in the question was 10000 per second). I feel that the snippet above may not be a good fit.

Currently I am trying to implement this web service with node.js, and more specifically [express-mung](https://github.com/richardschneider/express-mung).

**My question has two parts:**

1.**What would be a more performant way** to implement the add-a-tag-to-every-word logic?

2.(Optional)**What stack adjustment do I need** if answering the first question is not enough to solve this problem?(I am open to learning anything new)

Thanks a lot for answering this question.

Comment: Your rate requirement (10 000/sec) is really enormous. To implement a nodejs service to retrieve that many web pages, mung their markup, and send them to user browsers will require a large number of servers or a server less (aws lambda-style) approach, and may require an elaborate caching scheme. Doing it with a web extension in users' browsers may be a better way to deliver this functionality. It's called "sticking your users with the power bill."

Comment: I guess I'll put more effort to the caching, and less effort to the concurrency. Thanks O. Jones!